# Postgres: Selecting records where left joined records, all don't meet certain criteria

Tags: postgresql

For example I have a posts table and a users table.

users has, :post_id, :user_id, :published_date, :body

What I want to do is select users that have never set a published_date on any their posts.

I was thinking start with user then left join posts table but im not sure what to put on my where clause as it needs to on pick out users where all their posts don't have a published date

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you give a more detailed DDL of your tables. But you get the idea, you have to do a left outer join from `users` to your `posts` table, and select from this junction only `users` that dont have a `published_date` as not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id 
having bool_and(published_date is null)
```

[bool_and](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html)

> `bool_and(expression)` - `true` if all input values are true, otherwise `false`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @CoryCharlton There is a complete and correct answer here. Please read the answer in instead of just racing for revision reputation.

Comment: There is a code example and a link that may go dark in the future. It is not a good answer IMHO...

Comment: @CoryCharlton That link will always point to the __current__ version of the Postgresql manual. The code is correct and solves the question. In my opinion it is a good answer. This is a programming site and code here is very important. Post you own answer if you have a better one.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that. Websites go down, routing/DNS issues occur, they might change the URL pattern (ie: add a language identifier), etc. I edited your answer and made it more useful. Have a great day.

Comment: @CoryCharlton The manual quoting is a nice addition. Thank you for that. You could have done that in the first place in instead of the dirt and cheap bashing.

Comment: More importantly, this would not work for a user that has no post

Comment: @personne The requirement: _select users that have never set a published_date on any their posts_ As I understand that excludes users with no posts. Only the OP can clarify.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto As I understand it, a user that has no post has never set a published date on any of their posts, so users with no post should be included (getting users that have no published post makes sense and would often be useful, and otherwise the problem would be too simple to be interesting). But I agree that the OP should clarify.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
SELECT user.user_id
FROM user
LEFT JOIN post ON post.user_id=user.user_id AND post.published_date IS NOT NULL
WHERE post.post_id IS NULL
```

You match each user with his posts that have a published date. If there are none, the left join will return null values for matchings in the post table (even for columns that should never be NULL such as the post_id primary key). You use this in your WHERE clause to return only rows with no match.

Comment: what your saying doesn't make sense

Comment: Please explain yourself and try the query. Left join/where NULL is a classic pattern. My apologies if my explanations are not easy to understand, but I think saying it "makes no sense" is quite the overstatement.